# jquery slide scroll function

Tags: jquery

i have problem deploying Vertical Page Scrolling where the function went wrong.

Let say i have 3 sample navigation and contents [Home], [About Us], and [Services]. Now if i am going to click About Us after Home button, it will scroll-down correctly to About Us. And if i am going to click Services button after About Us button, it will scroll-up back to Home instead of scroll-down to Services button. And sometimes if you double click the same button, it will scroll-back and forth to next content and to your current content page.

```
$(function() {
    $('menu a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('#main, section').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
        if you don't want to use the easing effects:
        $('#main, section').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        */
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

here's my site link [Customer Site](http://verticallending.net/_dev/) so you can see the actual codes and function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but try:

```
.....
$('#main, section').stop().animate({
scrollBottom: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().bottom
}, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
```

Comment: um, thanks for the reply.
although the current code you mentioned will command only to scroll bottom.

here's what i mean for the scroll issue. [Home] [About Us] [Services] if i click About Us after Home button, it will scroll-down correctly to About Us. Now if i am going to click Services, it will scroll-up to Home instead of scroll-down to Services. And to that, if you double click the same link it will scroll-up back to Home which gives annoying navigation to each contents.